# unity somehow captures Control+G from Emacs

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, emacs

When I press `Control+G` in Emacs (`C-g` in Emacs's conventions), it does not do what it is supposed to do, eg quit from a minibuffer, instead it just blinks "Quit" but remains there (so I exit with `C-]` etc). At the same time, pressing `Ctrl` make a rippling orange dot at the mouse pointer, so I am assuming that Unity is capturing something.

Emacs in a console (`emacs -nw`) works fine, `C-g` is passed through. This is not an effect of some configuration I have (I tested with `emacs -Q`), or a particular Emacs version (I tested with 23, 24, and the current snapshot). Using wily/xenial.

Is there a way I could prevent Unity from interfering with this key?

**EDIT** I figured it out: if I disable *Show location of pointer* for the mouse in `gnome-tweak-tools`, `C-g` is passed through correctly. 
**EDIT2** This is [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1541935). (I won't delete the question so that others can find it.)